# nolearn 0.5 are not compatible with lasagne 0.1 or 0.2?

Tags: python-2.7, python-import, theano, lasagne, nolearn

When I want to import:

```
from nolearn.lasagne import NeuralNet
```

I always got this error

```
"cannot import name mse".
```

My Theano version is 0.7.0.

Answer (score 3):

I uninstalled nolearn and lasagne:

```
pip uninstall nolearn
pip uninstall lasagne
```

And then run following in command line:

```
pip install -r https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dnouri/nolearn/master/requirements.txt https://github.com/dnouri/nolearn/archive/master.zip#egg=nolearn
```

Now it works.